# basic question from vector analysis

Tags: vector-analysis

Let $\vec v = (a,b,c)$ be a constant vector and let $\vec r = (x,y,z)$
denote the position vector. Consider the vector field $\vec v \times \vec r$. A straightforward
calculation (using determinants or a vector identity) shows that
$\nabla \times (\vec v \times \vec r) = 2\vec v$. In order to get
a better understanding of this result, a sketch of the vector field helps to
convince one that indeed its curl should be $\alpha \vec v$ for some positive
constant $\alpha$ .

Question: Are there any further insights from physics, geometry, topology, etc.
          which help to explain why the constant should turn out to be 
          $\alpha$= 2 ?

Comment: In mechanics, expressed in polar coordinates, Coriolis acceleration is $2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}$.

Answer (score 0):

We can get some insight if we generalize the expression to other dimensions. Since the cross product is only defined for 3-D, we need to generalize in the language of [Geometric Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_calculus)

First, generalize the cross product using

$$ \vec v \times \vec r = (\vec v \wedge \vec r)^*$$

where the $^*$ denotes dualization (geometric-complement). Therefore

$$ \nabla\times(\vec v \times \vec r) = (\nabla\wedge(\vec v \wedge \vec r)^*)^*$$

Now, the RHS is defined for arbitrary dimensions.

Computing it for 2-D, we get
$$ (\nabla\wedge(\vec v \wedge \vec r)^*)^* = \vec v$$

In 4-D:
$$ (\nabla\wedge(\vec v \wedge \vec r)^*)^* = -3\vec v$$

In general, in n-D (a conjecture at this stage, I haven't written a proof yet):
$$ (\nabla\wedge(\vec v \wedge \vec r)^*)^* = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}(n-1)\vec v$$